# How would I fix this code to make it trim the trailing zeros and decimal point

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to trim the trailing 0s and decimal point, I tried the following code and it wouldn't work. I'm using PostgreSQL and the end result would look something like (from displaying 1234.00 to "1234 ft")

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING "0" FROM ROUND("Length"::numeric * 3.28084, 2)) || ''ft'' AS "Length"
```

Error code I'm getting:

```
ERROR:  column "Length" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM ROUND("Length"::numeric * 3.28...
                                            ^                       ^
```

Comment: what's your question ?   you have error? show error message ... wrong result show you actual result and your expected

Comment: Just added the error code

Comment: are you sure  you have a column name "Length" in your table  ???  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select concat(substring(cast(cast(1234.00 as decimal(10,2)) as varchar(50)),1,
position('.' in cast(cast(1234.00 as decimal(10,2)) as varchar(50)))-1),' ft')
as Length
```

Test Result:

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d380001ac329172e1b19467bd716913d)

Update:

I just found an easier one

```
select concat(cast(1234.00 as decimal(10,0)),' ft') as Length
from ...
```

Replace 1234.00 with your column name and add 'from' clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do:

```
SELECT ("Length"::numeric * 3.28084)::int || 'ft' as Length
```

You can `round()` as well.  The point is to convert to an integer so you have no decimals.